# DataGridView заполняется пустыми строками

Tags: c#, datagridview

Пытаюсь заполнить `DataGridView` в форме значениями из списка:

```
public partial class TeachDisciplines : Form
{
    public class Discipline
    {
        public int Number { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Discipline(int v1, string v2)
        {
            Number = v1;
            Name = v2;
        }
    }
    List<Discipline> disc = new List<Discipline>();
    public TeachDisciplines()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //DiscList.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        disc.Add(new Discipline(1, "Программная инженерия"));
        disc.Add(new Discipline(2, "Математический анализ"));
        DiscList.DataSource = disc;
    }
}
```

Таблица заполняется пустыми строками. Список вроде бы не пустой. Свойства элементов списка тоже публичные. Что ему ещё не хватает?

Comment: А если раскомменитить `//DiscList.AutoGenerateColumns = true;`?

Comment: @AGS17 Помогло, но не так, как хотелось бы. http://imgur.com/8LGeoi7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам требуется установить колонкам имя своств из ваших моделей:

Для колонки `№` - `DataPropertyName = "Number";`

Для колонки `Название` - `DataPropertyName = "Name";`

```
public TeachDisciplines()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    //DiscList.AutoGenerateColumns = true;

    DiscList.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "Number";
    DiscList.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "Name";

    disc.Add(new Discipline(1, "Программная инженерия"));
    disc.Add(new Discipline(2, "Математический анализ"));
    DiscList.DataSource = disc;
}
```

К слову, в настройках колонки в дизайнере есть соответствующий пункт для настройки привязки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подробнее про [`DataGridViewColumn.DataPropertyName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.datapropertyname(v=vs.110).aspx)